# The quantity of one fourth of a glass or a cup

Tags: word-request

You need the bartender to refill your glass up to one fourth. Is there a word for the quantity  in English? In my native language we say *tahpeyk* which literally means *the bottom of the shot glass*. The word is also used casually for liquids other than alcohol. For example, one can say, 'Pour me a tahpeyk' when a friend asks him if he wants any tea while playing cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also ask the bartender for "a finger".

> A finger more of the same.

But not of something poured into a shot glass.  This request assumes [a wider-mouthed glass](https://www.google.com/search?q=glass%20of%20scotch&num=20&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&source=iu&pf=m&ictx=1&fir=CuK_Upk3-ovXDM%253A%252CUvNLug-US0hclM%252C_&usg=__Ynmn36175Xa_vNxlbRStMOVcsz8%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj518aB7r3XAhUF4iYKHXN5D5wQ9QEILDAB#imgrc=ge05oci2X0cuvM:) with relatively straight walls, not a small conical glass.

Comment: Good call! However, in the UK, any bartender would ask you if you meant one measure or two, unless they were very familiar with your drinking habits.

Comment: @Mick: American bartenders are understood to have special telepathic powers which let them instantly assess any patron's drinking habits. It is our version of "The Knowledge".

Comment: You're right there. The Texan bartenders that I have known automatically poured me a *Shiner* as soon as I walked through the door. Lovely stuff!

Comment: They know better than you do what you want to drink. It's uncanny.

Answer (score 1):

In English-speaking countries, alcoholic spirits (such as whisky) are normally sold by the *shot* (or *measure*), the size of which varies from country to country. In the USA, it is normally 50ml; and in the UK, it is either 25ml or 37.5ml, depending on the establishment.

> [**shot**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shot) noun [C]
>   ​
>   a small amount of an alcoholic drink:
>
> a shot of whisky
>
> [**measure**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/measure) noun [C]
>
> an exact amount, especially of alcohol:

Cambridge Dictionary

If one wanted two measures of spirits (in the same glass), one would ask for a *double* (or *large*) [type of spirit].

Comment: It sounds like the OP is asking for a (possibly informal) word for 1/4th of a shot, not a shot.

Comment: @J.R. You could be right. Actually, I forgot about *dram* and *tot* (not to mention *finger*). My brain isn't working.